# Golang mapstructure.Decode does not parse all fields

Tags: json, go, decode

I'm using mapstructure.Decode function in Golang to convert a map to a nested structure, but it does not work correctly and some values got lost in the decoded structure. Following is a minimum case which contains a part of my code ( playground: https://go.dev/play/p/scS7gWyETGy ):

```golang
// Events represent repository events
type Events []Event

// Event represent a repository event
type Event struct {
    ID      string `json:"id"`
    Type    string `json:"type"`
    Payload struct {
        PushID      int         `json:"push_id"`
        Action      string      `json:"action"`
        Size        int         `json:"size"`
        PullRequest PullRequest `json:"pull_request"`
    } `json:"payload"`
}

// PullRequest represents pull request from github api
type PullRequest struct {
    URL   string `json:"url"`
    State string `json:"state"`
}

func main() {
    strg := "[{\"created_at\": \"2024-01-19T05:32:35Z\", \"id\": \"34950536433\", \"payload\": {\"action\": \"reopened\", \"pull_request\": {\"additions\": 1, \"number\": 23, \"state\": \"open\", \"url\": \"test.com\"}}, \"public\": true, \"type\": \"PullRequestEvent\"}]"
    evts := []interface{}{}
    events := Events{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(strg), &evts)

    mapstructure.Decode(evts, &events)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", events[0])
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", events[0].Payload.PullRequest)
}
```

As expected, the output should be like:

```bash
{ID:34950536433 Type:PullRequestEvent Payload:{PushID:0 Action:reopened Size:0 PullRequest:{URL:test.com State:open}}}
{URL: test.com State:open}
```

But actually I got following result:

```bash
{ID:34950536433 Type:PullRequestEvent Payload:{PushID:0 Action:reopened Size:0 PullRequest:{URL: State:}}}
{URL: State:}
```

I think it's a very simple case which should not get any problem, but the fact is not. Could anyone give me some help to figure out what the problem with it?

I wonder to know if there's a bug in the library `mapstructure` or I made some mistakes when using it.

Comment: Why are you using `json` tags, when using with `mapstructure`?. Refer package documentation to add how to add mapstructure tags for struct fields - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure#section-readme

Comment: @Inian I want to reuse the json tags and don't want to write the same tag twice. It seems that mapstructure uses the field name instead of the json tag.

Comment: @jianliangwang json and mapstructure both use the field name in the absence of a tag. json uses json tags, mapstructure uses mapstructure tags. In your case, mapstructure doesn't do anything and you could just use json to unmarshal directly into `Events`.

Answer (score 3):

Mapstructure doesn't parse the fields with '_' (underscore) in the name. You need to instruct it do do so properly:

```
PullRequest PullRequest `json:"pull_request" mapstructure:"pull_request"`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the problem. Instead of add tags, I use the configuration of the decoder:
```golang
 decoder, _ := mapstructure.NewDecoder(&mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
  TagName: "json",
  Result:  &event,
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

The mapstructure library expects the input map to have a structure closely matching the target Go struct. If the nested structure in the input map doesn't exactly match the nested struct in Go, the library may not decode it correctly.

In your case, the PullRequest struct inside the Event struct is not being filled because the keys in your JSON don't directly correspond to the nested struct format expected by mapstructure. The mapstructure library is looking for a direct match for each field, and it's not finding a match for the nested PullRequest struct.

Here are a couple of ways to address this issue:

**Flatten the Structure:**

Modify your Go structs to mirror the flat structure of the JSON. This means removing the nested struct and instead placing all fields directly within the Event struct. This can be a bit messy but is a straightforward approach.

**Use JSON Unmarshal Directly:**

Since your input is JSON, consider using `json.Unmarshal` directly into the Events slice, instead of first unmarshaling into an `[]interface{}` and then using mapstructure. This approach is more straightforward and leverages the standard library's JSON decoding, which handles nested structures well.

Here is how you might use `json.Unmarshal` directly :

```
func main() {
    strg := "[{\"created_at\": \"2024-01-19T05:32:35Z\", \"id\": \"34950536433\", \"payload\": {\"action\": \"reopened\", \"pull_request\": {\"additions\": 1, \"number\": 23, \"state\": \"open\", \"url\": \"test.com\"}}, \"public\": true, \"type\": \"PullRequestEvent\"}]"
    events := Events{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(strg), &events)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", events[0])
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", events[0].Payload.PullRequest)
}
```